# My div wont stay in my div container

Tags: html, css

I have a few divs in a table and I want to make one of my divs so that it doesn't go off the page. I want to add a scroll on the container div. but instead, I the div still goes off my page:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
     <tr>
         <td>
             //some stuff
         </td>
         <td>
             <div id="container" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
                 <div style="width: 1100px;"> div containing chart1 </div>
                 <div style="width: 1100px;"> div containing chart2 </div>
             </div>

         </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9zvTA/)

Comment: which div are you talking about exactly? The div which contains the text 'div containing chart1 and 2'?

Comment: please post your full html and css

Comment: yes, the two divs containing chart1 and chart2 are getting pushed off the screen

Comment: I think it might have to do with the table: I don't think scroll works the way it's intended for inside table cells. Why do you use tables anyway? You could reduce your code to <div id="wrapper"><div id="SomeStuff">..</div><div id="container">..</div></div> And then add CSS float if you want to display the inner divs side by side.

Comment: Your `width` setting is far too wide for your page is what I can assume. Why not use `div style="width: 100%;"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of `overflow-x:scroll` on the container. Then add an extra div inside each of the divs you want to scroll:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="scroll">
        <div class="chart">div containing chart1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll">
        <div class="chart">div containing chart2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can give the "scroll" divs a width of whatever (say 200px) with `overflow-x:scroll`, and set the inner "chart" div's to `width:1100px`:

```
.scroll {
    width:200px;
    overflow-x:scroll; 
}
.chart {
    width:1100px; 
}
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gQQL/)**

UPDATE:

Tom is right, you can apply a percentage width to the "scroll" div. Just make sure you add `overflow:hidden` to the body element, otherwise the hidden part of the table will overflow the page:

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.scroll {
    width:20%;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Updated **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gQQL/1/)**

Comment: Just as an addition to your text: the key point here is, you need to define the (max-)width of the parent div to make scrolling possible. If you don't have that setting the parent div will be resized instead.

Comment: thanks for the insight guys. However, I don't really want to set the width of my parent div. If a user has a big screen, I wouldn't want their div to still be small. Is there a way I can define my widths from my table by using percentages?

Comment: @roshambo I'm not a 100% sure, but I don't think that using `px`s should be a problem, even in large screens.

Comment: @AkshatTripathi specifying a px amount is exactly my problem. I can't put the outer divs to be 300px or something since that will restrict the screen-size available.

Comment: You can also use percentage values, but this value need to be assigned to the container with the `overflow-x: scroll` setting.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the width you had specified for the cells was much more than required (set to to a lower value and also try to use some CSS to specify the height and width of the table itself).

So, the width here:

```
<div style="width: 1100px;"> div containing chart1 </div>
```

should be less, here is the updated fiddle:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zvTA/1/)

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted your answer, but I guess it's because your answer isn't quite right. The problem wasn't the too large size of the child divs, the problem was the missing `width` setting in the parent div. See symlinks answer.